# Django distinct selection

Tags: python, django, django-views

i have this model:

```
class Person:
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    sexe = models.TextChoices('M', 'F')
    arrival_date = models.DateField(max_length=30)
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

It turns out that the same person can be registered several times (only the arrival date and the reason change).
I would like to make a query that lists distinctly persons. For example, if a person is registered many times, he will be selected only once.

How can i do it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for mysql

```
Person.objects.filter(positive = 1).order_by().values('first_name').distinct()
```

for Postgre:

```
Person.objects.order_by('first_name').distinct('first_name')
```

[Documentation Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

Answer (score 1):

you can get data in this way:

```
Person.objects.values_list('first_name', 'last_name', 'sexe').distinct()
```

Comment: It worked, but it return only those fields (first_name, last_name, sexe) in form of a tuple. How can i get all the fields ?